# How do you email source code without getting flagged as spam?

Tags: email, attachment, spam

When replying to a post (for example on Craiglist) that asks for sample code, is there a way to be (reasonably) sure of delivery?

Here's the problem, stated as possible options and the negative outcomes:

1. Link to the source code on an external site. In this case, there's a spam score metric based on number of external links that you could hit. Often your signature might contain a link.
2. Attach it in a zip. Zip files are often considered in spam metrics and in some cases are just outright removed. This also creates an extra step for the recipient which isn't much but has to be multiplied by the number of received responses.
3. Attach it as source code files. This one I'm not sure of but I suspect that some source code types, like javascript, could get flagged.
4. Inline the source code. This is messy for anything over a couple lines and I expect could be problematic if your source includes html, javascript or even urls.

So those are all the ideas I have and none are optimal or give me a good feeling my email will show up looking as I intend. Has anyone solved this problem already?

*Clarification*: This is about a first-time email. So the person you're replying to has given their contact info but has never received an email from you and may be receiving numerous replies a lot like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer links to external services or my own server, where the code is usually browsable, syntax-highlighted, etc ..

Comment: I'd definitely use something like this.. that way they can download updates, rather than you having to email them every single change.

Comment: I do link to my portfolio page but don't have browsable code samples there yet. Good idea.

Comment: I personnaly use gist.github.com but it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 6):

I usually send a link to my SVN repository.
another option is [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one file just rename it as a text file.

Comment: Doesn't an intelligent spam filter look inside the text file? There was also an exploit a while back where a second extension (like .txt.exe) was used to try to hide the real content type, making me suspect that might be watched for too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't send code as email. I put my stuff online using Dropbox and send a download link only.

http://www.dropbox.com/

Works perfectly for me and my team.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like:

http://www.sourcepod.com/
or
http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 0):

A zip file seems fine.  It shouldn't get flagged unless there are executables in it.  If you have an externally linkable SVN repository, that'd be ideal for some companies, and overkill for others.

Comment: I once worked somewhere that stripped all zip files based only on the file extension. The standard practice was to rename them as ".piz" files (and instruct anyone mailing us to do likewise).